# Cordova Ionic App - Push Notifications not working on Android 12 & Android 13 - cordova-android 11.0

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-android

I have an Ionic App using Cordova & Angular.

My push notifications are and were working fine for all iOS users and Android version <= 11 users.

We started getting a lot of reports that people weren't getting push notifications. I bought an Android phone running Android 11 to test it and it was working fine for me until I upgraded to Android 12. Now I do not receive push notifications anymore.

I tried upgrading my cordova-android to 11.0, I've tried upgrading Ionic from 5 to 6, I've upgraded all my other plugins and nothing seems to work.

There's no error messages in the console when I inspect it via Chrome Everything seems to be working per norm.

I send my push notifications via Firebase.

If you have any ideas what to try next it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since Android 13, push notifications are disabled by default, and users should be prompted by the app to choose what behaviour they prefer (meaning that you have to ask permission to show notifications somewhere in an activity). This should not however impact Android 12. Also, devices that have upgraded from Android <= 12 to 13 while having the app installed will not have their notification permissions changed, so notifications should work anyway. It's all explained here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like notifications are not working with @havesource/cordova-plugin-push.

I was able to resolve the issue by installing the dev version 4.0.0.dev.0

```
cordova plugin add @havesource/cordova-plugin-push@dev
```

As shown in this comment:
https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push/pull/185#issuecomment-1290450721